# HTML or ASP for a website

Tags: html, asp.net

I am an electrical engineer with some free time and I decided to use that to create a website for a non-profit for free. I only know HTML and CSS and I thought I would buy some space from FatCow or GoDaddy and host a simple website there. But people have warned me recently that HTML sites can be easily hacked and that I should code in ASP.NET instead. Some have said that Wordpress is more secure. So is HTML really that unsecure?

Please can someone advise me how to proceed.

Comment: nothing can be more secure than a pure static html website, you need to lean what's dynamic and static...go for a blog instead

Comment: I guess it's better to start with something like this: http://www.ehow.com/how_42_create-first-web.html

Comment: @Mahdi better to go for a blog..

Comment: Security vulnerabilities hardly exist in HTML / CSS; only some proprietary CSS features like Microsoft's `expression` can be dangerous. Starting with JavaScript (XSS), forms with server-side technology (CSRF) and working with server-side technologies have real risks (for example RFI, SQL injection) if you don't code securely.

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes, I agree with you, however it's good to have a general idea about that also ...

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I am not web-savvy and I have worked in electronics h/w all my life. Thanks for clearing the misconceptions that people dumped on me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid you've been horribly misled.

ASP.NET uses HTML (and CSS and JavaScript) to display web pages. You cannot write a web page without using HTML.

Also, HTML is a markup language, not a piece of software. It only describes the layout of web pages, so there is nothing insecure about HTML.

WordPress also uses HTML, because WordPress is a web application. Everything you see in a browser, on any web site, whether it's WordPress, ASP.NET, Java, PHP, Django or whatever else, uses HTML to display the page.

You cannot make a web page without using HTML, and there is nothing insecure about HTML.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. I am clueless when it comes to web-technology and I have dealt only with voltages and currents my whole life ! Now I can go ahead happily and make this site !

Answer (score 2):

A purely static HTML+CSS site is as secure as it gets. The security risks that you'll be facing will be regarding the software that'll be used in the server where you'll host your site, not on the HTML and CSS itself.

Regarding the security of a web-app (if you choose to dwelve into de programming world), it really is up to the programmer to keep it safe, no matter what language you'll be using. Some common safety guidelines can be read here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

If you want to do something more fancy, with comments and such, and with minimal effort I'd go for Wordpress (just make sure it always is up to date). It has a many templates to play with.

In the mean time, try to get more information on dynamic sites so you can get a better grasp of the web-apps world.